How to filter the list of Files displayed for a Case?
This is the list that we are currently seeing:

The problem is that, for Cases that have been created from e-mails, a lot of the files are useless: these are the typical icons in signatures of users. After a few e-mail exchanges, a Case typically has dozens of files, most of which serve no purpose.
The above screenshot features previews of the files. These previews are not available in the list that you see after clicking "View All". Also, the columns in that list are fixed, so we cannot add a preview column.
To enable users to quickly find relevant files, we can think of the following solutions:

Filter the displayed files (e.g. only show those with size > 3 KB)
Add a preview column to the View All list
Delete all files with size < 3 KB

We tried adding a Dynamic Related List, but for Cases only a few objects are available for such a list, none of them being EmailMessage or File. Because, to make life even more complicated, the files that you see for a Case, do not have the Case as a parent. Instead, the relation is via ContentDocumentLink objects, which link EmailMessages to Files. The EmailMessages are related to Cases.
